# How Can I Use Site ID To Make API Calls?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, site

## Problem

I'd like to use the SharePoint API (***cannot** be the Graph API*) to get information from site resources, and I would like to do this in one call to avoid problems with URL changes to the site in the future.

### Initial Attempts

I have tried a few approaches to this, namely:

1. `https://TENANCY.sharepoint.com/_api/site/GetById('SITE_ID')/...`
2. `https://TENANCY.sharepoint.com/_api/sites/GetById('SITE_ID')/...`
3. `https://TENANCY.sharepoint.com/_api/site/OpenWebById/...`

Nothing seems to get me there, unfortunately.

### Reasoning

This would, essentially, then allow me to use the ID to access site resource details with impunity to most user actions on the site barring complete removal.

If you would like an example of something that can only be got from the SharePoint API, then perhaps think about list views data. However, I cannot stress enough that this should not to be taken as the exclusive goal here.

Is there a way to do this?

---

## Investigation

### Microsoft Docs

There is nothing that I could see on the API page, here: [Complete basic operations using SharePoint REST endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)

### 3rd Party Resources

#### SKainet SharePoint API Explorer

I also heavily rely on this amazing resource, but have not *yet* found what I want from it:

https://s-kainet.github.io/sp-rest-explorer/#/

Answer (score 0):

Yo! I think I stumbled a challenge same as what you have. In my case, I was trying to get a property of a site by querying but it turns out you can actually get it from an existing object in SharePoint pageContext with out doing a query, you just need to pass the context and all the basic information about the site, permissions, and even the current user info are there. I got the idea from [here](https://tipsbybits.com/other/actually-its-already-in-the-sharepoint-pagecontext/), hope it helps somehow.

Happy SharePointing!

Comment: Hmm, not sure that I can put all that into a single REST API call, but it's intriguing for the future! Thanks. :-)

Comment: I mean, you don't have to do a single query, the object is already present in the Context. If you only want simple data like current user info, site info, list info, etc. The object is there already in the context.

Comment: Yeah, no, I do get that, I may have to settle for using '_api/site/GetWebPath' immediately before the call to the intended site. I just don't like things that are not immutable, is all. It presents the opportunity for a client to find an error.

Answer (score 0):

The below REST API endpoint will give you the details of **root** SharePoint site in your tenant:

```
https://TENANCY.sharepoint.com/_api/site
```

And it does **not** have any `GetById` resource/endpoint which can identify the site collection (site) in your tenant with unique ID - to get the resources of that particular site collection.

Also, most of the SharePoint site resources will be relative to site address only. For example:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/web?$select=Id,Title
```

This gives you the site Id and site Title.

However, `GetById` resource/endpoint is available for "lists" and "views".

For example:

For list:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/_api/web/Lists(guid'aa28e6df-50b3-42a3-9b3f-6f25e2dcc220')
```

For list view:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/_api/web/Lists(guid'aa28e6df-50b3-42a3-9b3f-6f25e2dcc220')/Views(guid'fd8a386f-67c9-4b29-b5fe-3edd63c65e6e')
```

Also, check below documentations once and see if you can find any helpful resources which you can use:

1. [REST API reference and samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/jj860569(v=office.15)?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)
2. [JavaScript API reference for SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj193034(v=office.15)?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)

Comment: OK, so not in one call, then. Cheers, though, @69998! :-)

Comment: Yes, correct. You're welcome!

Comment: No, Ganesh, I am indicating to you that your response is most definitively not the answer. Aplogies if my kind way of putting that was unclear to you.

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately, you cannot get all resources under the site using "single" API call. It is not supported by SharePoint REST API.